# If I have heap allocated member in my struct, do I have to allocate the struct itself in the heap?

Tags: c++, c, heap-memory

```c
struct Vector {
    size_t size;
    char ** data;
} Vector;
```

I have a vector struct. Do I have to allocate the Vector on heap if the struct has dynamically allocated data?

Update:

Does that applies the same in c++ class?

Comment: While the same is true in C++, generally you want to hide implementation details by using smart pointers or string class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no such rule.  A pointer residing in any part of memory may point to any other part of memory.

That said, if your `struct Vector` is allocated in a different way than its `data`, then the two might end up with different lifetimes, and it might be harder to avoid use-after-free bugs or memory leaks.  So if `data` is dynamically allocated, most of the time you will *want* `struct Vector` to be dynamically allocated too.  But it's not a requirement.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, appreciate it man!